# Scala: Specifying public method overriding protected method

Tags: scala, methods, overriding, clone, protected

I'm writing a `trait` that should specify the method `clone` returning a `CloneResult`, as so:

```
trait TraitWithClone extends Cloneable {
  def clone: CloneResult
}
```

The intention here is to tighten up the return type of `java.lang.Object`'s `clone()` to something useful to this interface.  However, when I try to compile this, I get:

> error: overriding method clone in trait View2 of type ()CloneResult;
>   method clone in class Object of type ()java.lang.Object has weaker access privileges; it should be public;
>   (Note that method clone in trait View2 of type ()CloneResult is abstract,
>   and is therefore overridden by concrete method clone in class Object of type ()java.lang.Object)

How can I require that an implementation be `public`, when Scala doesn't have the keyword?  I know I can do:

```
trait TraitWithClone extends Cloneable {
  override def clone = cloneImpl
  protected def cloneImpl: CloneResult
}
```

...but that seems like a hack.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `override def clone(): CloneResult` work?

Comment: No; that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Went back and tried that, but no beans.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the important part of the error message: "and is therefore overridden by concrete method clone in class Object".

You should provide an implementation of the `clone` method in your trait.  It's not ideal, but it's what you have to do since `clone` is a concrete method on `Object`.

```
trait TraitWithClone extends Cloneable {
  override def clone: CloneResult = throw new CloneNotSupportedException
}
```

Although, usually you just do this sort of thing in your concrete class directly:

```
class Foo extends Cloneable {
  override def clone: Foo = super.clone.asInstanceOf[Foo]
}

scala> new Foo
res0: Foo = Foo@28cc5c6c

scala> res2.clone
res1: Foo = Foo@7ca9bd
```